# How can I get the values of every item in a section?

Tags: python, list, parsing, configparser

I have a configuration file with one section, and multiple items with different values. I want to put all the values (not the variables) into a list. For example:

example.ini

```
[main]
apple: green
orange: orange
strawberry: red
banana: yellow
```

example.py

```
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('example.ini')

values = config.values('main')
for v in values:
    print v
```

That would print:

```
green
orange
red
yellow
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`.items(section)` method](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.items) with a list comprehension:

```
values = [v for k, v in config.items('main')]
```